# Properties are not mapped, empty Entity, Breeze with NoDB/PHP/Doctrine

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've provided metadata by defining a Model (so far only one Entity/Model):

```
function init(store){
        addSerieType(store);
    }

    function addSerieType(store){
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Serie",
            namespace: "xxx",
            defaultResourceName: "Serien",
            //autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties:{
                id: { dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                kat: { dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32, isNullable: false },
                bez: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, maxLength: 64, isNullable: false, 
                    validators: [ breeze.Validator.required(), breeze.Validator.maxLength( {maxLength: 64})]     // Add client-side validation to 'title' 
                },
                jahr: { dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32, isNullable: false },
                grp: { dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32, isNullable: false },
                bem: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, maxLength: 1024, isNullable: false, 
                    validators: [ breeze.Validator.maxLength( {maxLength: 1024})]     // Add client-side validation to 'title' 
                }
            }
        });

        store.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Serien", "Serie");
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Serie", null, serieInitializer);
    }

    function serieInitializer(serie){
        serie.errorMessage = ko.observable();
    }

    return{
        init: init
    }
```

The returning JSON from PHP/Doctrine includes columns `$id="Serie.id"` (e.g. 1,2,3 ...) and `$type="Serie"`. All column and property Names are lower case, NamingConvention is set to none. I get an empty entity - with default values as provided.

For a test I've created a new entity like this:

```
var s = manager.createEntity("Serie", { id: 42, bez: "Test1", jahr: 2999} );
```

This works, I get `ko.observable` properties in the entities an the entity is materialized to the cache.

Why don't I get entity from JSON result? I've set has Server Metadata to false, provided a model, everything is matching, but ... the entity is empty. No errors at all. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your query look like? Breeze needs to know the EntityType returned for any query, this can be accomplished via *any* of the following:

- Via the ResourceName/EntityType mapping established in the
  MetadataStore. This can be added to using the
  MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName method
- Via a toType() call
  on your EntityQuery()
- Via specification within either the
  DataService's or the EntityQuery's JsonResultsAdapter.  The "default" JsonResultsAdapter assumes JSON.NET serialization, which is unlikely to work for a PHP backend, so you may want to create a custom JsonResultsAdapter for PHP and add it to your DataService.

The standard symptom that Breeze is unable to map your query results to an Entity type is that the results do not get turned into "observables". If Breeze cannot determine the EntityType of any returned results it simply leaves them in their 'native' json format.

Comment: I've tried the toType call, and the returned JSON includes the $id and $type columns -> just like the JSON.NET results. So the raw results shoukd be mapped to the entity. I've also tried a custom JsonResultsAdapter but get always an entity-no-found error. The $id and $type column sholud do the trick - and the Serie entity is created- but all the properties are empty. Can you post some Code/Link für a custom JsonResultsAdapter? I've tried Edmunds from the Breeze Samples but got the same Problems. Thanks.

Comment: Try calling the MetadataStore.getEntityType method with the name in the $type column. My guess is that it will return 'undefined'. If so then you can also call the MetadataStore.getEntityTypes method to see all of the entity and complex types that you have defined. My guess is that you have a naming issue.

Comment: ok, that's correct. There are no EntityType defined. So something in my model/metadata must be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I've solved this. The getEntityType() / getEntityTypes() call return the correct Entity - the properties are still empty, but ko.observables.

Comment: now everything is working fine - I started from scratch like descripted in this two answers. Thanks again to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Please review [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892111/why-are-my-breeze-js-entities-not-creating-ko-observables) where I walk you through diagnosis. The person who posed that question is also using a PHP server.

Comment: great, that's exact my problem. I just can't see why raw json is not mapped to Entity but createEntity from the manager works fine. For testing I've put all the code in my datacontext. Did you see anything missing in my model? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(This may help anyone)

If you are working with Doctrine 2 (PHP) and breeze js, you might try this library: https://github.com/adrotec/breeze.server.php