# SPA Using BreezeJS, Durandal and Knockout: No getProperty method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze, durandal

I'm working a SPA based application as a proof of concept and have a problem.

My SPA is using BreezeJS, Durandal, Knockout and WebApi. For the data access layer I'm using Entity Framework 5 in a code-first approach.

I've got two classes, as follows:

```
public class TodoList : IEntity
{
    public TodoList()
    {}

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TodoItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class TodoItem : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    public TodoList TodoList { get; set; }

    public int? TodoListId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my web project I've created a view and viewmodel to list all of the TodoLists (viewmodel is as follows - I've condensed the code into this viewmodel as I'm actually using the repository and unitofwork patterns from samples on the BreezeJS website):

```
define(['services/entitymanagerprovider', 'plugins/router'],
    function (entitymanagerprovider, router) {

    var todoLists = ko.observableArray();
    var provider = entitymanagerprovider.create();
    var manager = provider.manager();

    function activate() {
        var entityTypeName = "TodoList";
        var resourceName = "data/TodoLists";

        if (entityTypeName) {
            entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityTypeName);
            entityType.setProperties({ defaultResourceName: resourceName });
            manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName(resourceName, entityTypeName);
        }

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                        .from(resourceName);

        manager.executeQuery(query)
             .then(function (data) {
                return todoLists(data.results);
             })
             .fail(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
             });
    }

    return {
        activate: activate,
        todoLists: todoLists
    };
});
```

However, when I run the page I get the following error:

*Object # has no method 'getProperty'*

I've investigated the error and it's happening in the BreezeJS code.  I believe one of my entities isn't being wrapped by an EntityType, which means the 'getProperty' function can't be called... Though that's just a very rough guess!

I've checked the relationship between the two objects in my data access code, and I have exposed foreign keys and parent object on the child (TodoItem).

As an aside, I've actually got another SPA prototype using the same techniques as above, but it's using the previous versions of BreezeJS and Durandal.  The other SPA works, but I'm getting the error when I use the SPA I'm working on at the moment.  The versions I'm currently using are:

BreezeJS: 1.4.2 (metadata version 1.0.5)

Durandal: 2.0.0

Any help would be massively appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Curiously, why are you returning the result of assignment from your query success function (`return todoLists(data.results);
`)? Yes it is "truthy" ... which means if Durandal is calling this activate, it will proceed. You make the reader wonder what you're doing. I used jsFiddle to see that observableArray assignment expression returns the parent object (for chained assignment) if there is one and returns Window if this is a private variable (as in your example). I would rather this function return something "meaningful"; even `true` would be more meaningful ... or at least less mysterious.

Comment: Apologies about that.  I'd left the return statement in by mistake as in my full example I'm using repository and unit of work patterns and returning a promise from the repository function that's being called.  So in this example previously I was returning the promise to make Durandal wait for it to resolve before proceeding.

I created and tested this cut down example for this post.  I've updated the activate function to not return anything and I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the problem on and off for a few days I've managed to solve it.  Firstly, I should state the the problem was caused by me making a very basic error.  I got to the solution by simplifying the problem and following the steps outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892111/why-are-my-breeze-js-entities-not-creating-ko-observables) SO post:

The initial error I was receiving was:

*Object # has no method 'getProperty'*

I was receiving this because Breeze was unable to map my query results to an entity type.  Therefore, my entities weren't wrapped by Breeze and so didn't have access to the 'getProperty' function.

So, to fix this I simplified down as far as I could go (as suggested in the post by Ward) and after removing a lot of the complexity I realised my WebApi calls weren't returning the type information needed by Breeze to map my query results to an entity type (for example, my JSON result was as follows):

```
[
    {
    Id: 1,
    Name: "List 1"
    },
    {
    Id: 2,
    Name: "List 2"
    }
]
```

When I saw this I realised that I'd make a really basic error and that the problem was that I was missing the [BreezeController] attribute on my WebApi controller.  So when I updated my controller as follows:

```
[BreezeController]
public class DataController : ApiController
```

The JSON payload then became:

```
[
    {
    $id: "1",
    $type: "SJCNet.Todo.Model.TodoList, SJCNet.Todo.Model",
    Id: 1,
    Name: "List 1"
    },
    {
    $id: "2",
    $type: "SJCNet.Todo.Model.TodoList, SJCNet.Todo.Model",
    Id: 2,
    Name: "List 2"
    }
]
```

Then everything worked as expected.

So, in short it was a very basic error I made.  But while trying to figure it out I've learnt a lot about Breeze and honed my problem solving skills.  The main lesson here being when trying to solve a problem I need to simplify... simplify... simplify...